# How to invert numpy matrices using Singular Value Decomposition?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

(Before you tell me, yes, I know you should *never* invert the matrix. Unfortunately for my calculations, I have a matrix which I have constructed, and it must be inverted somehow.)

I have a large matrix `M` which is ill-conditioned. `numpy.linalg.cond(M)` outputs a value of magnitude `e+22`. The matrix `M` is shaped `(1000,1000)`.

Naturally, `numpy.linalg.inv()` will result in many precision errors. So, I have used `numpy.linalg.solve()` to invert the matrix.

Consider that the matrix inverse `A^{-1}` is defined by `A * A^{-1} = Identity`. 
`numpy.linalg.solve()` computes the “exact” solution, x, of the well-determined, i.e., full rank, linear matrix equation ax = b.

So, I define the identity matrix:

```
import numpy as np
iddmatrix = np.identity(100)
```

and solve:

```
inverse = np.linalg.solve(M, iddmatrix)
```

However, because my matrix is *so* large and *so* ill-conditioned, `np.linalg.solve()` will not give the "exact solution". I need another method to invert the matrix.

1. What is the standard way to implement such an inverse with SVD?
2. How could I make this ill-conditioned matrix....well-defined?

Any recommendations are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, if it's feasible to calculate a `svd`, you can easily use it to calculate a pseudo inverse. The pseudo inverse will be your inverse if your input matrix is invertible

Comment: Have you seen `numpy.linalg.pinv` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html)?

Comment: I don't get it. Don't you have a square matrix? Why not LU decomposition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what taking the SVD of a matrix actually means. It means that for some matrix `M`, then we can express it as `M=UDV*` (here let's let * represent transpose, because I don't see a good way to do that in stack overflow).

```
if M=UDV*:
  then: M^-1 = (UDV*)^-1 = (V*^-1)(D^-1)(U^-1)
```

But thanks to the fact that `U`'s columns are the eigenvalues of `MM*` and `V`'s columns are the eigenvalues of `M\*M`, the inverses of these matrices are their own transposes (since eigenvectors are orthogonal). So we get: `M^-1 = V(D^-1)U*`. Taking the inverse of a diagonal matrix is as easy as taking the multiplicative inverse of each of these elements.

Better typesetting (kind of) here: http://adrianboeing.blogspot.com/2010/05/inverting-matrix-svd-singular-value.html

Answer (score 3):

Since SVD factorizes your matrix *A* as *U*S*V*, where *S* is diagonal and *U*, *V* are orthogonal, its inverse is *V'*inv(S)*U'*, and the inverse of a diagonal matrix is just the inverse of numbers on the main diagonal.

```
>>> A=np.random.rand(1000,1000)
>>> u,s,v=np.linalg.svd(A)
>>> Ainv=np.dot(v.transpose(),np.dot(np.diag(s**-1),u.transpose()))
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works? I guess you need matrix multiplication here.

Comment: np.dot _is_ matrix multiplication. This answer performs the operation described by Jack Meagher's answer.

Comment: Won't `s**-1` fail when one of the singular values is 0?

Answer (score 1):

the first argument of the dot product should be `v.transpose()`:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv

def svdsolve(A):
    u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(A)
    Ainv = np.dot(v.transpose(), np.dot(np.diag(s**-1), u.transpose()))
    return Ainv

temp = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
np.allclose(svdsolve(temp), inv(temp))
>>> True
```

`np.linalg.solve` factorizes the initial matrix as A = USV, so the inverse is just V' S<sup>-1</sup> U'

Comment: this works, but wanted to hear about the execution time, it seems compared to a standard np.linalg.invert this method takes mane order more...very slow infact , so not feasible for batch proceeses